# Delay pixel search

Tags: autohotkey, sleep

```
f1::    
enterPixelSearch,x1,y1,1,100,200,100,0x000000,2,Fast RGB 
    if(ErrorLevel == 0)
    {
        sleep, 20
        send
    }
```

How do I add a sleep to the enterpixel search itself? I want to delay the function after pressing the hotkey

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?:

```
f1::
Sleep 1000
enterPixelSearch,x1,y1,1,100,200,100,0x000000,2,Fast RGB if(ErrorLevel == 0) { sleep, 20 send }
return
```